# Does f(x) is differentiable

Tags: limits, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

I need to determine whether the following function is differentiable at $x_0 \ne 0$ according to the **derivative definition**:

$$ f(x) = x^\frac{1}{3} $$

So I started by looking at the definition but not sure how to proceed:
$$ f'(x_0) =\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{x^\frac{1}{3} - x_0^\frac{1}{3}}{x - x_0} $$

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Do u know the formula of a^3 - b^3 ? Then use it .rest is easy.

Comment: I know it but not sure how to apply it here..

Comment: @Noam, just factor $x - x_0$ = $(x^\frac13)^3 - ({x_0}^\frac13)^3$ as difference of cubes.

Comment: Put x^(1/3) =1 and x_0^(1/3)=b